# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

```
def cnn_data(data):
    x, y = data.shape[1:]
    return data.reshape((-1, x, y, 1))
```

We introduce this function used in the following code.

```
model.fit(cnn_data(self.train_X), np.array(self.train_y),
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=num_epochs,
                      verbose=1,
                      class_weight=class_weight,
                      validation_data=(cnn_data(self.val_X), np.array(self.val_y)),
                      shuffle=True,
                      use_multiprocessing=True,
                      callbacks=[tensorboard, early_stopping])
```

The code produces the following error. It tries to train a convolutional neural network.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 808, in <module>
    dd.train()
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 283, in train
    cnn = self.train_cnn_hyperparameters()
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 653, in train_cnn_hyperparameters
    model.fit(cnn_data(self.train_X), np.array(self.train_y),
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 776, in cnn_data
    x, y = data.shape[1:]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Looks like your data only has 2 dimensions, and you're trying to unpack the 2nd and third

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code `x` and `y` are two values while `data.shape` is producing only one value:

```
x, y = data.shape[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you data has 2 dimensions, so data.shape[1:] is only one integer. Hence the error message